# Using LaTeX Beamer to display code

Tags: python, latex, beamer

I'm using the following LaTeX code in a Beamer presentation:

```
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
  \centering
      \tiny
   \lstset{language=python}
         \lstinputlisting{code/get_extent.py}
   \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Is it possible to select specific lines from my get_extent.py file rather than displaying it all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `beamer`; it's about a `listings` feature. Its excellent [manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) has more. For example:

```
\lstinputlisting[firstline=2,lastline=5]{code/get_extent.py}
```