# Is there a good and fast way of printing (on paper) code's syntax highlight?

Tags: printing, syntax-highlighting

I'm going to a farm. I think there are no computers there, and my laptop is broken. I want to print out the code of some of my projects on A4 paper so I can review it while I'm there. It would be nice if it was printed with syntax highlighting.

**Editors:** Vim, Notepad++

**Code:** Html, CSS, Javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/)

[pygmentize](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/)

Comment: OK never mind. PS here's a much more appropriate link for this question, given the languages he wants: http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/#lexers-for-web-related-languages-and-markup I found it from the page you linked to.

Comment: How can I use these tools together? Or do I even need to??

Answer (score 2):

- [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) tool produces nice PostScript files for program listing printing.
- Vim has [`:TOhtml`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#convert-to-HTML) command which produces HTML with current open file highlighted according to Vim syntax coloring. GVim has `Syntax -> Convert to HTML` menu for this.
- If you use LaTeX, look at [listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) package ([pdf documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) at [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/)). It's a very good solution for including your code in documentation/[presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135339/using-latex-beamer-to-display-code).

All these tools support syntax of many programming (and non-programming) languages.

Comment: Vim also has `:hardcopy > output.ps` to print to PostScript instead of HTML.

Answer (score 2):

In emacs use `ps-print-buffer-with-faces`. There is also `ps-print-region-with-faces` for those occasions when you only want part of a file...

Use `M-x <command>` to invoke commands by name. Use `C-h f <command>` for help on a command and also to learn what (if any) keybinding it has.

Answer (score 1):

[Editplus](http://www.editplus.com/) prints with syntax highlighting intact

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found after an hour search is this vscode extension:

identifier: "pdconsec.vscode-print":

[image]

You can either print it right away or save as pdf and print later(with highlighted syntax of course!)